# Upload files to DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE instead of GridFs with mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, gridfs, mongoengine

I want to be able to store files in amazon s3. The FileField in mongoengine seems to be hardcoded with gridfs.

What can I do to achieve this?

Is there a custom filefield out there, that behaves like the regular django FileField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent seen an S3 FileField for use with MongoEngine - so currently, you'd have to roll your  own implementation - you could use a `StringField` to store the location or you could create your own `proxy_class` like `ImageField` but it is quite tided to GridFs but I'm happy to abstract that away if needed.

As always pull requests welcome!  https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine